# Adding header to all .csv files in folder and include filename

Tags: csv, header

I'm a command line newbie and I'm trying to figure out how I can add a header to multiple .csv files. The new header should have the following: 'TaxID' and 'filename'

I've tried multiple commands like sed, ed, awk, echo but if it worked it only changed the first file it found (I said *.csv in my command) and I can only manage this for TaxID.

Can anyone help me to get the filename into the header as well and do this for all my csv files?

(Note, I'm using a Mac)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is on way in perl that modifies the files in place by adding a header of `TaxID,{filename}`, ignoring adding the header if it thinks it already exists.

```
ls
a.csv   b.csv

cat a.csv
1,a.txt
2,b.txt

cat b.csv
3,c.txt
4,d.txt

ls *.csv | xargs -I{} -n 1 \
perl -p -i -e 'print "TaxID,{}\n" if !m#^TaxID# && !$h; $h = 1;' {}

cat a.csv
TaxID,a.csv
1,a.txt
2,b.txt

cat b.csv
TaxID,b.csv
3,c.txt
4,d.txt
```

You may want to create some backups of your files, or run on a few sample copies before running in earnest.

**Explanatory:**

List all files in directory with .csv extenstion

```
ls *.csv
```

"Pipe" the output of ls command into xargs so the perl command can run for each file. `-I{}` allows the filename to be subsequently referenced with `{}`. `-n` tells xargs to only pass 1 file at a time to perl.

```
| xargs -I{} -n 1
```

`-p` print each line of the input (file)

`-i` modifying the file in place

`-e` execute the following code

```
perl -p -i -e
```

Perl will implicitly loop over each line of the file and print it (due to `-p`). Print the header if we have not printed the header already and the current line doesn't already look like a header.

```
'print "TaxID,{}\n" if !m#^TaxID# && !$h; $h = 1;'
```

This is replaced with the filename.

```
{}
```

All told, in this example the commands to be run would be:

```
perl -p -i -e 'print "TaxID,{}\n" if !m#^TaxID# && !$h; $h = 1;' a.csv
perl -p -i -e 'print "TaxID,{}\n" if !m#^TaxID# && !$h; $h = 1;' b.csv
perl -p -i -e 'print "TaxID,{}\n" if !m#^TaxID# && !$h; $h = 1;' c.csv
perl -p -i -e 'print "TaxID,{}\n" if !m#^TaxID# && !$h; $h = 1;' d.csv
```

Comment: Thank you JRD that worked like a charm!! Could you give me bit more detail about which part does what in your code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it, there are certainly others:

```
$ for i in *.csv;do echo $i;cp "$i" "$i.bak" && { echo "TaxID,$i"; cat "$i.bak"; } >"$i";done
```

Here's a sample run:

```
$ cat file1.csv
1,2
3,4
$ cat file2.csv
a,b
c,d
$ for i in *.csv;do echo $i;cp "$i" "$i.bak" && { echo "TaxID,$i"; cat "$i.bak"; } >"$i";done
file1.csv
file2.csv
$ cat file1.csv.bak
1,2
3,4
$ cat file1.csv
TaxID,file1.csv
1,2
3,4
$ cat file2.csv.bak
a,b
c,d
$ cat file2.csv
TaxID,file2.csv
a,b
c,d
```

Breaking it down:

```
$ for i in *.csv; do
```

This loops over all the files ending in `.csv` in the current directory. Each will be put in the shell variable `i` in turn.

```
echo $i;
```

This just echoes the current filename so you can see the progress. This can be safely left out.

```
cp "$i" "$i.bak"
```

Copy the current file (whose name is in `i`) to a backup. This is both to preserve the file if something goes awry, and gives subsequent commands something to copy from.

```
&&
```

Only run the subsequent commands if the `cp` succeeds. If you can't make a backup, don't continue.

```
{
```

Start a group command.

```
echo "TaxID,$i";
```

Output the desired header.

```
cat "$i.bak";
```

Output the original file.

```
}
```

End the group command.

```
>"$i";
```

Redirect the output of the group command (the new header and the contents of the original file) to the original file. This completes one file.

```
done
```

Finish the loop over all the files.

For fun, here are a couple of other ways (one JRD beat me to), including one using `ed`!

```
$ for i in *.csv;do echo $i;perl -p -i.bak -e 'print "TaxID,$ARGV\n" if $. == 1' "$i";done
$ for i in *.csv;do echo $i;echo -e "1i\nTaxID,$i\n.\nw\nq\n" | ed "$i";done
```

Comment: Thank you blm! I've tried a similar command (for i in *csv) earlier but I think I did some wrong with it, it only worked on the first file it found. Thank you also for you detailed code explanation!

Comment: @Kay You're welcome. It's hard to say why your attempt would have failed without seeing the whole command line, but you were on the right track.

Comment: Thanks blm! You really helped me to save plenty of time by your post. This works great for me.

Comment: @SankarChandraBose You're welcome, glad I could help.